# Using browsersync with docker (laradock)

Tags: docker, browser-sync, laradock

I'm running into a problem with running browsersync via Gulp inside a docker container. I'm using Laradock.

I tried to extrapolate from this answer: [Browsersync within a Docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42456424/browsersync-within-a-docker-container), but I'm only able to get the UI to show on port 3001.

It's unclear to me what I should have for proxy. I've tried many combinations such as:

```
function browserSync(done) {
  browsersync.init({
    proxy: 'workspace:22', notify:false, open:false
  });
  done();
}

// -----------------

function browserSync(done) {
  browsersync.init({
    proxy: 'workspace:3000', notify:false, open:false
  });
  done();
}

// ---------------

function browserSync(done) {
  browsersync.init({
    proxy: 'localhost', notify:false, open:false
  });
  done();
}
```

I've added 3000 and 3001 to docker-compose.yml under my workspace service

```
### Workspace Utilities ##################################
    workspace:
      build:
        context: ./workspace
        args:
          - LARADOCK_PHP_VERSION=${PHP_VERSION}
          - LARADOCK_PHALCON_VERSION=${PHALCON_VERSION}
          - INSTALL_SUBVERSION=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_SUBVERSION}
          - INSTALL_XDEBUG=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_XDEBUG}
          - INSTALL_PHPDBG=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_PHPDBG}
          - INSTALL_BLACKFIRE=${INSTALL_BLACKFIRE}
          - INSTALL_SSH2=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_SSH2}
          - INSTALL_GMP=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_GMP}
          - INSTALL_SOAP=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_SOAP}
          - INSTALL_XSL=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_XSL}
          - INSTALL_LDAP=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_LDAP}
          - INSTALL_IMAP=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_IMAP}
          - INSTALL_MONGO=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_MONGO}
          - INSTALL_AMQP=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_AMQP}
          - INSTALL_PHPREDIS=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_PHPREDIS}
          - INSTALL_MSSQL=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_MSSQL}
          - INSTALL_NODE=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_NODE}
          - NPM_REGISTRY=${WORKSPACE_NPM_REGISTRY}
          - INSTALL_YARN=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_YARN}
          - INSTALL_NPM_GULP=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_NPM_GULP}
          - INSTALL_NPM_BOWER=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_NPM_BOWER}
          - INSTALL_NPM_VUE_CLI=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_NPM_VUE_CLI}
          - INSTALL_NPM_ANGULAR_CLI=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_NPM_ANGULAR_CLI}
          - INSTALL_DRUSH=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_DRUSH}
          - INSTALL_WP_CLI=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_WP_CLI}
          - INSTALL_DRUPAL_CONSOLE=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_DRUPAL_CONSOLE}
          - INSTALL_AEROSPIKE=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_AEROSPIKE}
          - INSTALL_V8JS=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_V8JS}
          - COMPOSER_GLOBAL_INSTALL=${WORKSPACE_COMPOSER_GLOBAL_INSTALL}
          - COMPOSER_AUTH=${WORKSPACE_COMPOSER_AUTH}
          - COMPOSER_REPO_PACKAGIST=${WORKSPACE_COMPOSER_REPO_PACKAGIST}
          - INSTALL_WORKSPACE_SSH=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_WORKSPACE_SSH}
          - INSTALL_LARAVEL_ENVOY=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_LARAVEL_ENVOY}
          - INSTALL_LARAVEL_INSTALLER=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_LARAVEL_INSTALLER}
          - INSTALL_DEPLOYER=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_DEPLOYER}
          - INSTALL_PRESTISSIMO=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_PRESTISSIMO}
          - INSTALL_LINUXBREW=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_LINUXBREW}
          - INSTALL_MC=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_MC}
          - INSTALL_SYMFONY=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_SYMFONY}
          - INSTALL_PYTHON=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_PYTHON}
          - INSTALL_IMAGE_OPTIMIZERS=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_IMAGE_OPTIMIZERS}
          - INSTALL_IMAGEMAGICK=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_IMAGEMAGICK}
          - INSTALL_TERRAFORM=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_TERRAFORM}
          - INSTALL_DUSK_DEPS=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_DUSK_DEPS}
          - INSTALL_PG_CLIENT=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_PG_CLIENT}
          - INSTALL_PHALCON=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_PHALCON}
          - INSTALL_SWOOLE=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_SWOOLE}
          - INSTALL_LIBPNG=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_LIBPNG}
          - INSTALL_IONCUBE=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_IONCUBE}
          - INSTALL_MYSQL_CLIENT=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_MYSQL_CLIENT}
          - PUID=${WORKSPACE_PUID}
          - PGID=${WORKSPACE_PGID}
          - CHROME_DRIVER_VERSION=${WORKSPACE_CHROME_DRIVER_VERSION}
          - NODE_VERSION=${WORKSPACE_NODE_VERSION}
          - YARN_VERSION=${WORKSPACE_YARN_VERSION}
          - DRUSH_VERSION=${WORKSPACE_DRUSH_VERSION}
          - TZ=${WORKSPACE_TIMEZONE}
          - BLACKFIRE_CLIENT_ID=${BLACKFIRE_CLIENT_ID}
          - BLACKFIRE_CLIENT_TOKEN=${BLACKFIRE_CLIENT_TOKEN}
          - INSTALL_POWERLINE=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_POWERLINE}
          - INSTALL_FFMPEG=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_FFMPEG}
      volumes:
        - ${APP_CODE_PATH_HOST}:${APP_CODE_PATH_CONTAINER}${APP_CODE_CONTAINER_FLAG}
      extra_hosts:
        - "dockerhost:${DOCKER_HOST_IP}"
      ports:
        - "${WORKSPACE_SSH_PORT}:22"
        - "3000:3000"
        - "3001:3001"
      tty: true
      environment:
        - PHP_IDE_CONFIG=${PHP_IDE_CONFIG}
        - DOCKER_HOST=tcp://docker-in-docker:2375
      networks:
        - frontend
        - backend
      links:
        - docker-in-docke
```

I'm running apache on port 80, so my app can be seen at http://localhost

I'm able to access the UI at localhost:3001, but can't access localhost:3000.

Comment: Could you also share the Dockerfile?

Comment: @sebasaenz I no longer have this project, but it's using laradock, so you should be able to see more there: https://github.com/laradock/laradock. keeping question up because people are interested in an answer